# Perl command or module like Linux "file" command

Tags: perl, cross-platform, file-get-contents

I have a script that downloads files but these files do not have any information about them before they are downloaded. While writing for Linux I have just called `qx{ 'file ' . $filename }` to see if it is a JPEG image an if not delete it. However, I am now trying to rewrite to a platform independent and pure-Perl form. I have turned all the calls to `system{ 'curl',  $image_website }` to LWP::UserAgent calls and I was hoping that there is some way to replace calls to file with something as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`File::Type`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Type/)  CPAN module can help you - its description is "determine file type using magic" which is what Unix `type` command does.

```
my $ft = File::Type->new();
my $type_from_file = $ft->checktype_filename($file);
```

Another option is [`File::LibMagic`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::LibMagic) (Perl wrapper for libmagic; file-4.x or file-5.x)

Comment: Also: [File::MimeInfo::Magic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::MimeInfo::Magic).

Comment: Thanks to both of you. File::Type works but I am going to look into File::MimeInfo::Magic so that I can use File::MimeInfo's `extensions` function without having to require more CPAN modules than necessary.

Comment: File::LibMagic is the best, I made a comparison.

Comment: File::Type doesn't detect Word document files