# Perl File Test for Text -T and PDFs

Tags: perl, pdf

I'm trying to limit my Perl-Tk code to only open text files to edit.  I'm testing to make sure the user selected a valid file (I'm using Tks `getOpenFile()` ):

```
if ( (defined $file) and (-f $file) and (-T $file) ) {
  #work with file
}
```

The problem I've run into is that some PDF files pass the -T test and get opened (causing much chaos).  I tried this code in a directory full of PDFs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = <*>;
foreach (@files) {
  if (-T) { print "$_ is a text file\n"};
}
```

About 1/2 the PDFs in the directory get printed.

Am I using -T wrong?  Will I have to add a regex to filter out PDFs?  And how come Perl thinks only some of the PDFs are text?

EDIT: `-T` is a file test that should return true if the file is plain text.  I'm not trying to check for taint.

Comment: PDFs can be valid plain text files. Did you maybe check one of the files hit as plain text in a text editor?

Comment: That would explain it!  The text only PDFs pass, the mostly graphic ones don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have more success with the [File::Type](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Type/lib/File/Type.pm) or [File::LibMagic](http://search.cpan.org/~fitzner/File-LibMagic/LibMagic.pm) modules.

PDF is mostly plain text. Compression, images and encryption make them appear as binary. But simple PDFs are plain text to naive tests.

The [minimal PDF](http://zagaeski.devio.us/0004.html) from the specs in a simplyfied version is plain text:

```
%PDF-1.1
%íì¦"

1 0 obj
  << /Type /Catalog
     /Pages 2 0 R
  >>
endobj

2 0 obj
  << /Type /Pages
     /Kids [3 0 R]
     /Count 1
     /MediaBox [0 0 300 144]
  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
  <<  /Type /Page
      /Parent 2 0 R
      /Resources
       << /Font
           << /F1
               << /Type /Font
                  /Subtype /Type1
                  /BaseFont /Times-Roman
               >>
           >>
       >>
      /Contents [
        << /Length 105 >>
        stream
          BT
            /F1 18 Tf
            0 0 Td
            (Hello world.) Tj
          ET
        endstream ]
  >>
endobj

xref
0 4
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000019 00000 n 
0000000078 00000 n 
0000000179 00000 n 
trailer
  <<  /Root 1 0 R
      /Size 4
  >>
startxref
612
%%EOF
```

Comment: I think that's it, it never occurred to me that PDFs can be only text.  I'll try out File::Type.  Thanks

Comment: [File::LibMagic](http://p3rl.org/File::LibMagic) does a much better job than any [other detection module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788542/perl-command-or-module-like-linux-file-command). Use it instead. -- `libmagic` also underlies the `file` command mentioned in two other answers to this question.

Comment: Point taken, added to answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that one too

Answer (score 2):

You are using `-T` correctly: it is just a best guess rather than an absolute classification. It may help to know that PDF files carry a fourcc of `%PDF` which you can check easily with a subroutine like this

```
sub isPDF {
  open my $fh, '<', shift or return;
  read $fh, my $fourcc, 4;
  return $fourcc eq '%PDF';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most PDFs have a few binary characters right after the %PDF on purpose to hint that it's not (entirely) a plain text file. The PDF spec even recommends it:

> Note: If a PDF file contains binary data, as most do (see Section 3.1,
>   “Lexical Conventions”), it is recommended that the header line be
>   immediately followed by a￼comment line containing at least four binary
>   characters—that is, characters whose codes are 128 or greater. This
>   will ensure proper behavior of file transfer applica- tions that
>   inspect data near the beginning of a file to determine whether to
>   treat the file’s contents as text or as binary.

In @mugen kenichi's answer, you can see the `%íì¦"` that attempts to trigger this.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of suggestions:

- Have you tried with a newer Perl? The docs call -T a "heuristic guess", maybe they improved it.
- Kind of a hack, but you could try running 'file' on the files before opening them
- Another hack: read the first line after open() to see it it really is text.

Don't know why it fails though.. do you have a publicly accessible pdf file that passes -T ?

Comment: All of these are classed as *text* by my Perl 5.12
[ECMA 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), 
[Java Language Specification](http://www-sst.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/~db/doc/Java/The_Java_Language_Specification.langspec-2.0.pdf) and 
[Data Structures and Algorithms](http://docs.rtfm.us/Users/M2G/Algorithms/2_Data%20Structure%20and%20Algorithms/Data%20Structures%20and%20Algorithms%20-%20Alfred%20V.%20Aho.pdf)

Comment: My third point should work. I call it a hack because I don't know the pdf standard and "%PDF" might not be required on the first line..

Answer (score -1):

As @yvind Skaar pointed, try 'file' command.